# Showing a progressDialog from an OptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-optionsmenu

I know the following is probably not the best practice and not recommended to do.

I have an AsyncTask that sends data to server. The whole process that i need to do includes 4 web calls using this AsyncTask in quick succession.

I understand that with AsyncTask you must start and stop the ProgressDialog in OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute. I do normally do this.

The problem is that i call 4 AsyncTask in a row one after another, so i don't want 4 Progress dialogs repeating one after another.

I use AsyncTask.execute().get(), so they are called sequentially.

I call these AsyncTasks in a loop from the optionsMenu. What i am trying to do is set up a global ProgressDialog that i can start in the optionsMenu before the loop and cancel it after the loop.

The problem is that it doesn't show. I thought it may be because it needs to run on the UI thread so i placed it inside a Handler, but still no luck.

How can I show the progressdialog from the optionsMenu?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuclientassessment, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sendclientassessment:

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    progressDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(ClientAssessmentActivity.this);
                    progressDialog2.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
                    progressDialog2.setMessage("Sending the assessment to server...");
                    progressDialog2.setIndeterminate(true);

                    try {
                        progressDialog2.show();
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        //ignore
                    }
                }
            });

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                String [] params = new String[6];

                AssessmentScore as = null;
                as = arr.get(i);

                params[0] = clientID;
                params[1] = carerID;
                params[2] = comments.getText().toString();

                DateTime now = new DateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm");
                String formattedNowTime = df.print(now);
                params[3] = formattedNowTime;

                params[4] = as.getElementID();
                params[5] = as.getValue();

                AsyncSendAssessment asa = null;
                asa = new AsyncSendAssessment();
                try {
                    asa.execute(params).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }//end of loop

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        progressDialog2.dismiss();
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            //ignore
                        }
                }
            });

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the progress dialog be a class variable, then instantiate it when you create the activity. That way you can access it anywhere in the application.

Comment: This is what i sort of tried except i instantiated the dialog inthe OptionsMenu. When i instantiate it in onCreate as you suggest, it still does not show.

Comment: Try calling a class method outside of your handler to show the progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Create your dialog to be a class extending the class `Dialog`. For eg. - `TestDialog`. Then create a Util class with common functions using the dialog.

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog {
}
```

Util:

```
public class TestDialogUtil {
   public static TestDialog processingDialog;

   public static void createProcessingDialog();
   public static void dismissProcessingDialog();

}
```

Then in any of your Activities call `TestDialogUtil.createProcessingDialog` or `TestDialogUtil.dismissProcessingDialog`. You won't get extra dialogs getting created. Create a new Dialog only when `processingDialog` is not null.